# Find out what is the extention of the file downloaded from url?

Tags: javascript, cordova, url, download, file-transfer

I am trying to download the file from url :

http://distedu.ukma.edu.ua/mod/resource/view.php?id=5475

which redirects to some other url where the file really is.

The problem is that i need to save the file in a format that is readable. Is there a way to get the extention of file downloaded in such way?

My app is phonegap/cordova, but i can use anything that can work with HTML5 file api, i think. Or anything that gives the intermidiate data, instead of writing it right away to the file.

The files there are mostly either pdf or pptx.

EDIT:

i tried to get the mime type by seanding Head request:

```
var testUrl = window.location.href;
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open('HEAD', testUrl);
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == this.DONE) {
            console.log(this.status);
            var contentType = this.getResponseHeader("Content-Type");
            Debug.log(contentType.)
        }
    };
    xhttp.send();
```

Which gave me following string:

```
text/html; charset=UTF-8;
```

I assume this means did not bother specifying the more concrete type?

Comment: I know nothing about phonegap/cordova, but as a general rule the file extension is technically meaningless and the real information is contained in the *mimetype* - e.g., application/pdf for pdf or application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation for pptx.

Comment: @manassehkatz could you provide any option of getting the mime type from the download url in javascript?

Comment: In your sample above, `text/html` is the mimetype. I've never used HEAD request - it appears that it is supposed to give the same headers as a GET, but you might want to try the same code with a GET to see for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `mimetype` information to understand what type of file you are downloading.
You may want to check out [cordova-plugin-file-transfer](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/) plugin and [cordova-plugin-file-opener2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-file-opener2) plugin to help in your case.